# Why are int columns returned as string when using WordPress's $wpdb to get database rows?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've created a table to use within my Wordpress site, with columns using `date`, `int` and `varchar` as the type.

However, when I use `var_dump` to get the values of particular rows and results, it displays all the columns as `string`.

I haven't seen this actually affect the operation of the DB calls and functions, but I'm just wondering why they're all returning as strings, where I've seen core Wordpress functions in `var_dump` returning `int` values sometimes.

[image]

```
$bv_set = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT * FROM wp_before_after WHERE ID = '.$bv_id );

var_dump($bv_set);

C:\wamp64\www\bellavou\wp-content\plugins\bv-before-afters\views\edit.php:8:
object(stdClass)[6915]
  public 'ID' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'created' => string '0000-00-00' (length=10)
  public 'before_date' => string '2015-04-08' (length=10)
  public 'after_date' => string '2015-04-21' (length=10)
  public 'patientID' => string '2137' (length=4)
  public 'procedureID' => string '238' (length=3)
  public 'patient_display' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'procedure_display' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'gallery_display' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'before_img' => string '2200' (length=4)
  public 'after_img' => string '2199' (length=4)
  public 'period_taken' => string '1week' (length=5)
  public 'notes' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: it would be helpful to see the code *how* you retreive the values.

Comment: Yes, of course. Added the call to the DB, and the result of the `var_dump`, sorry.

Comment: whats in `get_row`? Assuming this is a wrapper method for executing the query/getting the result?

Comment: maybe [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129574/why-does-wpdb-return-strings-for-mysql-integer-values) might answer some questions

Comment: You can see the result of the get_row call in the var_dump

Comment: How the values are represented when getting data *back* depends on whether you have `mysqlnd` installed or not (MySQL Native Driver). It's an extension that can replace `libmysqlclient`, which is used by `mysqli` and `PDO`. Why do you need it? MySQL uses textual protocol and if there isn't some sort of driver that can tell PHP "hey, this value is an int", PHP has to do the safest thing which is casting everything to a string. `mysqlnd` helps PHP determine actual data types and how to accurately represent them within PHP. Also, answers provided so far are wrong, especially sitepoint one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the code of [`$wpdb->get_row`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/), you can see that it eventually calls [`$wpdb->query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/), which in turn calls `mysqli_fetch_object` (line 1822 at time of writing):

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $this->result ) ) {
    $this->last_result[$num_rows] = $row;
    $num_rows++;
}
```

Now, taking a look at the PHP documentation for [mysqli_fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php):

> Returns an object **with string properties** that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.

Which provides an answer to the question.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for doing this? Given that it doesn't seem to affect the operation of working with the DB row, is there a upside of returning everything as string?

Comment: @Lee that's a question for the developers of the PHP language itself.

Comment: You don't need to ask developers of PHP language anything because the decision is clear to the one who asks the right question. MySQL uses a text protocol to send data back to PHP. PHP doesn't know how to represent the data so it does the safest thing - considers everything a string. There's a library (that I mentioned in another comment) called `mysqlnd` which "fixes" this behavior. All it takes is a bit of research before coming to wrong conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

Highly depends on the mysql connector and it's type castings based on the DB field options like "null" values.  Might also be related to some notorious php type castings (see https://www.sitepoint.com/3-strange-php-facts-you-may-not-know/ )

Comment: if you code PHP badly, then yes those things on sitepoint might happen.

Comment: Answer was before the author of the question added screenshot + var_dump example :) - now its clear that he uses the wpdb class to query the data